# How can I get data from today set in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, select

My `updated` field is a DATETIME and that is what I want it to be.

```php
$date = '2020-03-24';
$sql = "
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(updated, '%Y-%m-%d') = " . $date. "
";
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

I get an empty result when doing the above.

### Question

How can I get the results where the date is from `$date` no matter what the time is? If I could use PHP I could use substr but this is not possible in sql.

Comment: why not just use `00:00:00`? satisfies MySQL and your problem without much more work. Or are you trying to get records from a date? In which case, I think there's a dupe somewhere

Comment: Just a note that in your SQL, the date needs to be in quotes (`'" . $date ."'`) although you should be using prepared statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(updated, '%Y-%m-%d') = '" . $date. "'
";
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

An efficient method would be:

```
where updated >= :date and updated < :date + interval 1 day
```

... where `:date` is the date parameter coming from your application.

A less efficient method is:

```
where date(updated) >= :date
```

This requires applying a date function on each and every record *before* filtering, which prevents the database from taking advantage of an existing index on the date column.

Comment: The first one does not work because $date is a string, not in integer. Therefor it can't compare it if it's bigger or smaller than updated.

Comment: @JensTörnell: MySQL understands date arithmetics... The first solution shoul work and be more efficient than the second, did you actually try it?